# Redirecting subdomain to query parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to convert URLs like subdomain.domain.fr to domain.fr/index.php/subdomain
I tried with that htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain.fr$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/%1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

With this, my site responds with domain.fr but I get a Internal Server Error with subdomain.domain.fr

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably getting looping error. You can use this code to avoid it:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).domain\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php/%1 [L]
```